# What is the difference between beacon products

Tags: hardware, bluetooth, beacons

What is the difference between different beacon products from different companies? I want to develop iBeacon products, but haven't decided yet which to use. It seems to me though they are quite similar because they are compatible with the iBeacon spec. Like what's the difference between Estimote and Bluvison? Looks work the same.

Comment: As posed, this question is hard to answer definatively. It would be better to ask 'What factors should I consider when picking a specific beacon'. It may seem the same, but SO users tend to dislike product recommendation questions. Why do you assume there is a difference?

Comment: I didn't assume they have difference. But if it's indifferent as a developer, what would be the reason to choose one over another?

Comment: price/availablity/form factor all of which we can't answer for your specific use case

Answer (score 2):

[TL;DR:](https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/BLE-Beacons-URIBeacon-AltBeacons-iBeacon/)

> iBeacons and AltBeacons are almost the same thing: they broadcast a
>   UUID from the beacon itself and use external databases to give beacons
>   meaning. iBeacons are closed source, Apple-branded, and widely used;
>   AltBeacons are open source and provide more data fields to use, but
>   few people use them yet. URI Beacons are different: they don't require
>   an external database, instead they use web links to either link to
>   data directly or, in the future, possibly as a two-way communication
>   method. That said there is a heavier app-side workload to URIBeacons
>   as compared with iBeacons or AltBeacons. iBeacons are currently the
>   most widely used, but I think URIBeacons have a great deal of untapped
>   potentia and will become a driving force of IoT in the future.

[Some](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-differences-between-iBeacon-Eddystone-AltBeacon)

[Other](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/what-is-iBeacon.html)

[Discussions](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-differences-between-Bluetooth-iBeacon-and-the-Eddystone-beacon)